# Body extending behind the bottomappbar, how to prevent it?

Tags: flutter, dart, bottomappbar

In my flutter app, i have a bottom app bar. when i scroll, the body goes behind the bottom app bar. I don't want this behavior. Is there any way to to show the app body always on the top of the bottom app bar?

[image]

[image: like this]

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet that will reproduce the issue?

Comment: I feel like what you really want is to put that button after the fields list.

Comment: you can add padding to bottom

Comment: @MickaelHrndz Is there no other way?

Comment: Why do you want another way ? Use slivers if you don't want to wrap your list with a `Column`

Answer (score 0):

just add this in scaffold  extendBody:false,